# Bluetooth headphone delaying sound

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I'm using a bluetooth headphone and it works fine until I pause the music/video for a few minutes. The headphone doesn't disconnect, instead it delays the audio when I start the music/video again. I can fix the problem by disconnecting/connecting the headphone again, but it's annoying.

Is there a way to fix this permanently?

Ubuntu 20.04
Headphone: Edifier W800BT

Comment: Could you please provide more information about hardware ?

Comment: Anything in particular? Ubuntu 20.04, Headphone: Edifier W800BT

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Bluetooth speakers, I used pavucontrol to correct the delay. you can install it through:

`sudo apt install pavucontrol`

and then launch it with:

```
pavucontrol
```

then go to output devices, select your Bluetooth headphones and click advanced and adjust the latency offset.